# FTP copy file to remote machine failed in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

I have made bash script which will backup files and send it to remote machine file gets created but ftp failed to put it to directory mentioned 
Problem lies all when ftp tries to copy the file.
Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash 
#BACKUP ROOT DIRECTORIES
DESTINATION="/backup";
HOST=localhost
USER=qwerty
PASS=qwerty
COUNT=$(cd /backup/ && ls -l | wc -l);
echo $COUNT;
DIR="/dev /sys /etc /www /var /rom /root /dev /overlay /bin /sbin /nebero /lib /usr";
DIR="/root/pen";
DIR_1="/dev /sys /etc /www /var /rom /root /dev /overlay /bin /sbin /nebero /lib /usr /mnt";
DIR_1="/root/pen";

    if [ "$1" = "FULL_BACKUP" ]
    then

        tar cvf $DESTINATION/full_backup_`date +%d-%m-%y_%H:%M`.tar `echo $DIR_1` >>/dev/null;

        if [ $COUNT -eq 1 ]
        then
        NEW=$(ls -t /*back*/ | head -n2);
        else
        NEW=$(ls -t /*back*/ | head -n2 | sed '2!d');
        fi  

    elif [ "$1"  = "CONF_BACKUP" ]
    then
        tar cvf $DESTINATION/conf_backup_`date +%d-%m-%y_%H:%M`.tar `echo $DIR` >>/dev/null;
        NEW=$(ls -t /*back*/ | head -n2 | sed '1!d');

    else
        echo "Please provide an argument";
        exit

    fi

FILE=$NEW

ftp -in $HOST <<EOF
user $USER $PASS
pwd
cd /rav
put $FILE
bye
EOF
```

Comment: What is the _specific problem or error_? Is $FILE put to some other directory? What is the output of the script?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like the purpose of all the `ls` commands is to find the file you have just created. You can skip all that if you just save the filename to a variable prior to calling `tar`:

```
FILENAME=full_backup_`date +%d-%m-%y_%H:%M`.tar
```

then use `$DESTINATION/$FILENAME` in the `tar` commands and `$FILENAME` in the `ftp` command.

Regarding the failed upload, are you sure that you are in the correct directory locally?

These are the FTP commands for changing directories:

- `cd`: Changes the directory on the remote machine
- `lcd`: Changes the working directory on the local machine

Make sure that both are correct before executing `put`.

Comment: actually, `cdup` changes the remote directory to its parent.  The command to change your local directory is `lcd`.

Comment: @rojomoke: Thanks for spotting that.